# Will Linux fonts ever be like windows ones?

Tags: windows, linux, fonts

I've read all the tutorials, i've tried everything...but i just know...that actually it's Impossible to get the same font rendering. And that's the only reason i can't just go with linux on Desktop. How much years do i have to wait?

Comment: Enough for the copyrights on Microsoft fonts to expire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will never get the same font rendering on Linux as on Windows as Windows font rendering (ClearType) is very strange, complicated and covered by patents.

To anyone who is used to a Mac system, windows font rendering looks wrong. The Mac font rendering renders fonts much closer to how they would look printed out. The Windows system tries to increase readability by reducing blurriness and aligning everything perfectly with pixels, but it does this at the expense of accuracy.

Linux's font rendering tends to be a bit behind, but is likely to be more similar to the Mac OS than the windows rendering as time goes forward. The fonts themselves are often made available by Microsoft for using on different systems, it's just the rendering that is different.

Comment: thank you, bad news. waiting for windows to become open source. waiting for never.

Comment: @develroot never say never...